# Populate documents or find documents by some query, which is better? (Mongoose/MongoDB)

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, rdbms

Suppose their is a user schema and product schema as follow:

```
userSchema: {
    name:{type:string},
    myProducts:[
       {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Product',
       }
    ]
}

productSchema: {
    name: {type:string},
    owner: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'User'
    }
}
```

User schema have array of products which has referenced from Product Schema and Prouct schema have owner referenced to User.

So for fetching all the products of particular user which of the following query is better and optimal.

1. const myProducts = await User.find({id: currentUser}).populate('myProducts');
2. const myProducts = await Products.find({owner: currentUser});

And which is better if we have to perform several funciton like pagination, search pattern etc.

Answer (score 1):

*Which is better* is quite vague. Are you talking about performance? Try calling both 10k times and measure the time. For conciseness and clarity of intent I would prefer 2.